# getting api data using getjson javascript

Tags: javascript, getjson

I'm trying to use this [api](https://eth.nanopool.org/api), to show data in my webpage. 
I want to fetch the data  and display it on a html paragraph.... I am using getJSON, but I couldn't make it work.. I am using AJAX to make a request.

Sample of the json data

```
{  
   "status":true,
   "data":{  
      "h1":0,
      "h3":0,
      "h6":0,
      "h12":0,
      "h24":0
   }
}
```

getjson code

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "https://api.nanopool.org/v1/eth/avghashrate/1",
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {

    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
   $('#results').html( json.data.h1);
}
 });
```

html code is

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `$.parseJSON()`, because `data` is already an `object`.

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api.nanopool.org/v1/eth/avghashrate/1",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(typeof data); // -- Object
      var json = data;
      $('#results').html(json.data.h1);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```